# Microsoft outlook mail format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

When I copy data from a table in Excel sheet and put it in mail body in Outlook logged in through microsoftonline.com, it shows like below and not like a table from excel sheet. Mail recipients are not able to read the data properly.

> Agent Team    Event   Aid/prop asked for
>
> asdf  Arshad  Singing Background karaoke track
>
> asdf  Raviteja    Singing Background karaoke track
>
> asdf  Archana Singing Background karaoke track

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a print screen or export the excel to a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your e-mail format is set to as "Plain Text", if Yes, then Change it to "HTML".